# My prof. gave me this problem which for me seems to be impossible to solve

Tags: limits, functions

I'm new here so first off: Please tell me if I need to provide more details or format something in another way. Thanks in advance!

So that's the problem my prof. gave me (I did my best at translating I hope it's accurate):

> There are 2 functions $f,g: \mathbb N → \mathbb R_{>0}$ for which
>   there is an existing limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$
>   also including the case $$\forall c > 0\,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\,\forall n \ge n_0 : \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \ge c \iff
>  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$$

Now he wants me to proof:

> $$f \in O(g)$$

What (unless I'm misunderstanding something here) can't be right. Because:

$$f \in O(g) \iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty$$

If the problem includes the case $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \infty$ this can't be right. (Or at least it seems to like that.)

I'm asking you here rather than my prof. because it's a really hard time talking to him. Also this problem is formally written down, so I couldn't have made a mistake onto that. I really hope It's just something I'm missing out on but I've no idea what that could be. However if you could find it, I'd really appreciate that.

*Problem solved. - I am the idiot.*

Comment: If limit exists, it cannot be equal to $\infty$

Comment: @vidyarthi Ok thank you. I guess that means I need to talk to him anyways... Rough times again...

Comment: @vidyarthi I read over the original again. I'm confident now that he meant to say that it should also include the case that it is equal to $\infty$ .

Comment: The case when limit is equal to $\infty$ is, I hope, wrong, because $\frac{e^n}{n}$ diverges as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but both do not grow in the same order.

Comment: @vidyarthi That's my confusion. I thought, that I'm missing out onto something. But I guess I will just need to talk to him.

Comment: @vidyarthi If you speak German I posted the original...

Comment: Are you talking about part $a$? It didn't ask you to show $f \in O(g)$. It asks you to show $$f \in O(g) \iff \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty$$ i.e. the condition $f \in O(g)$ is equivalent to the condition that the limit is finite.

Comment: @achille Oh... now I get it... Thank you... That's kind of emberassing.